# IsoDateTimeConverter does not produce correct format, and Angular client throws error when day is over 12 in "dd.MM.yyyy"

Tags: angular, date, asp.net-core, format, converters

I have stumbled upon to this issue with date formatting some time ago,
but I do not understand why it is yet.

It is an ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Angular 7 project. In `Product` class I define this property

```
 using Newton.Json;

 public class Product 
 {
     ...
     [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "dd/MM/yyyy")]
     public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
 }
```

The converter class is defined with NewtonSoft JSON.NET library:

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";//@"dd/MM/yyyy";
    }

    public DateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

I need to display this date in such format in Angular client. When I display date "05.08.2021", it goes smoothly, but when the day is more than "12", for example "14.08.2021", it leads to the error. It seems the format reads "dd" as month, but not days, as the error can begin from thirteen as day number.

Displayed error in Chrome browser console:

> InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "14.08.2021" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
>
> at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4140)
> at DatePipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.DatePipe.transform (common.js:5067)...

So I need just to uncomment this JsonConverter attribute to work without this error:

```
//[JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "dd/MM/yyyy")]
public DateTime CreationDate {get;set;}
```

Angular class is:

```
export class Product {
creationDate: string;...
```

The product date is displayed in Angular component in this way:

```
<td> {{product.creationDate |date:'dd/MM/yyyy/}}</td>
```

As your see in browser error message, the date also does not come
from server in defined by Json DateConverter format.

Without using this formatter at server, json objects (dto) contains
such datestring `creationDate:"2021-08-05T00:00:00".`

In the SQL Server database table, the date is saved in such a format:

```
2021-08-05 00:00:00:0000000
```

What is the reason of it, why this extended NewtonSoft Json.NET `IsoDateTimeConverter` does not work? Why does it produce the dot-divided-format?

Comment: Looks like there's a typo for the date format in angular - it's missing the closing quote: should be `{{product.creationDate |date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`

Comment: `<td> {{product.creationDate |value |date:'dd/MM/yyyy/}}</td>` is a syntax error

Comment: I missed closing quote as I manually entered this line, looking at angular code, and several date ones in the end of my topic. And where is syntax error, I did not used '|value'?

Comment: The first issue is that server json formatter provide the date in 'dd.MM.yyyy', but not in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format. Then Angular does not correctly read this format, when day is more 12, that is more then month quantity. So I do not know if such format 'dd.MM.yyyy' is envisaged in angular. Indeed it reads it partially.

Comment: I used Angular 7 version, and its datepipe could have flaws (that should be resolved in next versions as it was written at this forum), but I have doubts that it is in rendering this format. The server also provides not that expected.